# Oracle sql query - getting SUM() from another table using GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle

There are two tables:

**Employee table:**

```
employee_id, lname
E01        | Smith
E02        | Johnson
E03        | Williams
E04        | Jones
```

**Salary table:**

```
employee_id, paid
E01        | 199
E04        | 751
E01        | 599
E02        | 299
E03        | 259
E03        | 357
E02        | 671
E04        | 130
```

How do I query only the last names of the employee, and their *total* salary earned? My attempt drew too many rows:

```
SELECT lname, total_paid
FROM Employee
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(paid) AS total_paid FROM Salary GROUP BY employee_id);
```

My problem is, I need to `select` the total earned from the table paid, meaning I need to use `SUM` and `GROUP BY` if I'm not mistaken. However, I only want to select lname and the total...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the tables and then aggregate:

```
SELECT e.lname, SUM(s.paid) as total_paid
FROM Employee e JOIN
     Salary s
     ON e.employee_id = s.employee_id
GROUP BY e.lname;
```

Note:

- Use a `LEFT JOIN` if some employees have no salaries.
- This is the standard way to do what you want.  You could use a correlated subquery as well.
- The unaggregated column in the `SELECT` (`lname`) should be the one in the `GROUP BY`.
- All the columns are *qualified*, meaning they have table aliases.

Comment: @Joesph - Actually, this answer is **incorrect**. Think what happens if you have two employees with the same last name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `query` instead your. Just make left join on Salary table on employee_id columns.

```
SELECT Employee.lname,  SUM(Salary.paid) as total_paid FROM Employee
LEFT JOIN Salary on Employee.employee_id=Salary.employee_id
GROUP BY Employee.employee_id
```

Comment: Oracle sql developer gave me an error on the last GROUP BY line - "column ambiguously defined". If I used employee.employee_id or salary.employee_id, it says it's "not a GROUP BY expression".

Comment: Alias it like Salary.paid,Employee.lname,Employee.employee_id etc. But better idea is  use GROUP BY Employee.lname.

Comment: Thanks, got it now :)

Comment: @Joesph - This solution is incorrect, for the same reason I gave in a comment to Gordon's solution: What happens if you have several employees with the same last name?

Comment: The fix is incorrect too, now lname is not a GROUP BY column. You need to group by BOTH employee_id AND lname.

Comment: @mathguy You have right,  it have to be id not name, id should be always unique name not.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Gordon and mww's solutions is to aggregate first, and then do the join. (It is possible that the Oracle optimizer will transform one of the solutions into the other anyway, before running the query - I find this to be an interesting question, I will experiment and report back). This is also very close to what you tried - CROSS join was the mistake. You need to keep the `employee_id` in the subquery, and join on `employee_id`.

**Edit**: Actually the answer offered by Gordon and mww is incorrect. Both answers group by employee last name, ignoring the fact that there may be different employees with the same last name. So my "testing to see what the Oracle optimizer does" is moot; the queries are NOT equivalent. **End edit**

Another point is that the left join will leave the total_paid as NULL for an employee who does not have any corresponding rows in the salary table. If you need that to be 0 (zero) instead, you can use a `CASE` expression or its equivalent in this case, `NVL()`.

```
select e.lname, nvl(g.total_paid, 0) as total_paid
from   employee e left join ( select   employee_id, sum(paid) as total_paid     
                              from     salary 
                              group by employee_id
                            ) g
                  on e.employee_id = g.employee_id;
```

**Test results**

I compared my solution to Gordon's and mww's (assuming they are corrected to include both `lname` AND `employee_id` in `GROUP BY`; the other way to fix their solutions is to select `MAX(lname) as lname` and `GROUP BY employee_id` alone). I did this on the SCOTT schema, using the EMP and DEPT tables, summing salaries by department; pretty much the same problem.

The optimizer does NOT transform one solution into the other - one plan groups first and then joins, while the other joins first and then groups. The optimizer cost was the same (for the very small input tables) but the cardinality was greater if one joins first.

This is to be expected: suppose EMP has 1000 rows, but there are only 4 departments. If one groups first, the EMP table is aggregated down to 4 rows, which are joined to DEPT. On the other hand, if we first join, we are joining 1000 rows to 4 rows - and then we are still aggregating 1000 resulting rows down to 4, just as in the other solution. So the only difference is the cardinality of the join.

HOWEVER:  I repeated the same test on the HR schema. In this case the optimizer did transform one solution into the other - it first did the join and only then the grouping. The difference in this case is that there are indexes on department_id in both tables, and the optimizer can take advantage of that (and perform the join MUCH faster) but only if it joins first. If it groups first, there is no "index" on the resulting `department_id` column.

So: "it depends" (as with so many other things). In any case, IF there is an index and the optimizer thinks it is best to do the join first, it will do so. Apparently not the other way around though.